# live script to work with jquery cycle

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I don't know how can I code for the jquery cycle plugin.

cause this is working when the images are loaded previously

```
    $('#eventPic').cycle({
    prev:   '#previousButton',
    next:   '#nextButton',
    timeout: 0
});
```

but when the images are updated via ajax then it's not working

please help

here is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/FNsNG/

Dave

Comment: I assume you're referring to http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cycle plugin initializes when you call it. If you are loading images after it has been initialized then it is not going to have any idea that they exist. Perhaps in your ajax callback you should instantiate the cycle call. If you provide your html/ajax request someone may be able to give you more feedback.

Comment: yeah, it's what I figured. How is the cycle plugin supposed to know that you wiped out all the elements inside the div? Try reinitializing the plugin or calling it after you load the elements via ajax.

Comment: here, see this fiddle. Notice how clicking add image doesn't add it to the rotation. But if I click the reinitialize button it will now be included in the cycle - http://jsfiddle.net/FNsNG/3/

Comment: thanks mrtsherman, after applying the code according to your instructions and few modifications in cycle's js file, it's working.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery livequery plugin:

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery

```
$('#eventPic').livequery(function(){
    $(this).cycle({
    prev:   '#previousButton',
    next:   '#nextButton',
    timeout: 0
    });
});
```